# python webdriver failed to click button after page refresh

Tags: python, selenium, focus

I'm testing a web page. When I select something, then a pops up window appear

When the pops up window disappear automatically, then  when I want to try click another button. 
Failed to click the button, though the button can be found.

Is there any method for python with selenium to get the button be focused? Since the last click is not happened

test link: https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss

```
driver.get('www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/…) 
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys("7383AC1") 
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click() 
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'SLES for SAP Apps 8 Skt Virt Unlimited Subs Only 5Yr (5731SLX)')]")
id=element1.get_attribute('for') 
driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt=\"Continue\"]").click()
```

Comment: An example would be nice. What popup? Where? How is it created? What error message does you get? What code are you using? What browser?

Comment: My codes is like above. I've no idea about why there's no click event happen and also there's no any error msg @Arran

Comment: You last `click` operation is not calling the method. You have `.click` instead of `.click()`. Perhaps a typo but something to check at least.

Comment: @MarkRowlands, ah... that's a paste mistake. I've confirmed that ".click" is in my code.

Comment: Ok no worries. So the last `click()` isn't working. Is there an error or an exception?

Comment: @MarkRowlands. That's the most strange things. no error, no exception, and when check the code in debug , the last click() can be executed succesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked my code, get the problem to the time-out resolved

changed from:

```
wait=ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
```

to:

```
wait=ui.WebDriverWait(driver,300)
wati.until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_id("genMask_c")), 'visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code is working for me and able to click Continue,i added only time.sleep and changed the   object id locator

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss') 
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys("7383AC1") 
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click() 
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'SLES for SAP Apps 8 Skt Virt Unlimited Subs Only 5Yr (5731SLX)')]")
id=element1.get_attribute('for')
driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
time.sleep(70)
driver.find_element_by_id("continueBottom").click()
print 'done'
```

Comment: thanks. Just one more hmm... is there any method to confirm web page's status to instead of 'time.sleep'? –

Comment: @Stella you can make wait Until the IBM loading image disappears ..after that try to click on the continue button it should work

Comment: I've tried "wait until" to wait the image "Please wait..." not shown on UI, but always TimeoutException. Do u have any idea about it? Already, updated code as below answer